# Resharper Find-Replace Regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace, resharper

I am attempting to replace my WebInvoke headers with the correct REST header using Resharper's replace tool.

For example I currently have the following:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "{id}")]
```

and I want to replace it with

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{id}")]
```

When I use the Resharper tool, I have this as my search:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = $uri$)]
```

and this as my replace:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("$uri$")]
```

I have set uri as just an identifier. When I run it, it does not replace any of the webinvoke tags to the correct one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it makes sense to replace only this part or code

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate =
```

with this part of code

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route(
```

So you don't need to use $uri$

And actually you could do this replacement without Regexes:
[image]

Comment: it's expecting an expression for the first one. Doesn't seem to be working unfortunately

Comment: Just to make it clear: @BorisSokolov 's solution doesn't use ReSharper Replace tool, but build in Visual Studio Find and Replace dialog. And it doesn't expect any expression. So it should work.